# I can't see Grease Pencil keyframes in the dope sheet

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet, 2d

[image: dope sheet]

I can't see keyframes in dope sheet or grease pencil timeline. I am using blender 2.83. How to move my strokes from one frame to another?

Answer (score 1):

If you look down at the bottom on the dope sheet bar, you can see the little skewed arrow that's highlighted. Click that. That is "only show selected"