# Grease Pencil Keyframes not visible in timeline

Tags: animation, keyframes, grease-pencil, timeline

I am very new to blender, working on my first project. I am trying to combine a 3D model, animated using an armature, with some hand-drawn animation, using grease pencil. I started with the model, and everything worked as expected, but when I started animating with the grease pencil, the keyframes were not visible in the timeline. As a result, I cannot grab them, arrange them, or view their onion-skinning.

I saw a similar question asked about the [Dope sheet](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182372/i-cant-see-grease-pencil-keyframes-in-the-dope-sheet), which allowed me to see the keyframes there, but the timeline is still blank. I have a picture of the view, **with the grease pencil selected**, but with no keyframes visible. For reference: There are keyframes on frame 0, 1, and 20. I cannot see them in object, edit, or draw mode.
[image: Grease Pencil without Timeline]

I think my problem has something to do with using the wrong "Keying set" since I am using one with LocRotScale for the armature bones, But I am not sure how to change it to a keying set that allows for grease pencil frames. Keying sets are still a little confusing to me in general. I know the keyframes are being created because scrubbing the timeline still shows the different frames in the viewport, but I just can't view them in the timeline. I am most interested in getting the onion skinning working, which I believe is linked to this visibility issue.

[image: Keying Set Popup]

Any help is much appreciated. I've been at a bit of a stuck in the project because I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Switch from timeline to the dopesheet editor ( go to the timeline and press Ctrl tab) the timeline will only show the keyframes for the active object.

Comment: Is there a difference between the "active" object and the "selected" object? I know I can use the dopesheet (the other question I linked already answered that), but without the timeline, I cannot view the onion-skinning. Can I "Activate" the grease pencil then?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact problem, I have keyframes and there is animation, but the keyframes aren't visible anywhere, not even in graph editor even though the object is selected.

To fix the bug go to *Object Mode* and create a new grease pencil stroke. When going back to the original drawing keyframes show again.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is in Dope Sheet -> Crease pencil mode.

[image: Dope Sheet -> Crease pencil]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!

Turns out I locked the collection (where the grease pencil layer was) in outliner. Therefore I could not select the grease pencil drawings. You lock/unlock the collection or any layer by clicking the pointer icon to the right of the name of the collection/object/etc.

I realise that this might be a different problem, but maybe someone will find this helpful at some point in time :D

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Solved it by moving the Grease Pencil Object into a collection in *Outliner* and keys appeared again in the *Dope Sheet*.